# Compare and you'll see they're not all the same (Keep them LARGE)

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, odd-one-out

**Find the odd-one-out...**

---

```
Exist and in the right position
Exist and in the right position
Doesn't exist
Doesn't exist
Exist and in the right position
Exist but in the wrong position
Exist but in the wrong position
Doesn't exist
Exist and in the right position
Exist but in the wrong position
Doesn't exist
Exist but in the wrong position
Exist but in the wrong position
Doesn't exist
Exist but in the wrong position
Doesn't exist
Exist but in the wrong position
Doesn't exist
Exist but in the wrong position
Exist but in the wrong position
Doesn't exist
Exist but in the wrong position
Doesn't exist
Doesn't exist
```

---

**...Oh, and explain why of course ;)**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The odd one out is the one highlighted in yellow:

> [image]

> These are all referencing the Greek letters in **CAPITALS** in the order that they appear in the [Greek alphabet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet).

> The ones that ‘don’t exist’ are the ones that are not the same as any **CAPITAL LETTERS** in the Modern Latin alphabet.

> The ones that ‘exist and are in the right position’ are the ones that are same as a **CAPITAL LETTER** and corresponds in positioning to the Modern Latin alphabet. For the ones that ‘exist but are in the wrong position’ they exist in the alphabet too but don’t correspond in positioning!

> The highlighted sentence stands for **OMRICON** and it ***DOES*** correlate with the positioning of the letter O in the Modern Latin alphabet!! (Letter 15). So this is the odd one out since the rest actually are the correct descriptions for their respective Greek Letter in Capitals.

Comment: Sniped me! (Although looks like I got the answer wrong anyway) Good job :)

Comment: I was beaten to the chase in the last prime numbah puzzle so I made sure I was extra speedy here!!

Comment: Nice job, this is the correct answer! And the last sentence was actually a subtle way of answering "find the odd-one-out..." rot13("Bu" -> B)